# XSLT checking values in multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, oxygenxml

I have the following XML, which I need to extract the param value based on a child node attribute using XSLT. 
In this case extract a list of the activities my students are part of:

**XML**

```
<students>
   <student id="1000020001"/>  
   <student id="1000020002"/>      
</students>   
<activities>
    <activity name="yoga beginners" start="2016-10-12" end="2016-12-17">          
         <members>            
              <member id="1000020001"/>              
         </members>
    </activity>
    <activity name="yoga intermediate" start="2017-10-12" end="2017-12-17">          
         <members>            
              <member id="1000020001"/>  
              <member id="1000020002"/>            
         </members>
    </activity>
</activities>
```

I want to create an XSLT which display the activities my students are part of, in this case I have:

**XSLT**
For each student:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/activities/activity">
   <b>Activity:</b>: 
   <xsl:call-template name="extractActivities">
      <xsl:with-param name="student-id" select="@id"/>
   </xsl:call-template>            
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template name="extractActivities">
    <xsl:param name="student-id"/>
    <xsl:if test="$student-id = /activities/activity/members/member/@id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I have the following two problems:

1. First XSLT displays "Activity:" twice as is doing the loop for each node.
2. No activity name is displayed

Comment: First of all, your XML is invalid for two reasons: The opening <activities> tag cannot have the leading slash, and there must be a single root tag (containing the <students> and <activities> elements).

Comment: Typo thanks for replying just corrected ot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to resolve cross-references by using a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)**:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="act" match="activity" use="members/member/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="students/student">
                <h3>Student: <xsl:value-of select="@id" /></h3>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('act', @id)">
                    <b>Activity: </b><xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **well-formed** input:

**XML**

```
<root>
   <students>
      <student id="1000020001"/>
      <student id="1000020002"/>
   </students>
   <activities>
      <activity name="yoga beginners" start="2016-10-12" end="2016-12-17">
         <members>
            <member id="1000020001"/>
         </members>
      </activity>
      <activity name="yoga intermediate" start="2017-10-12" end="2017-12-17">
         <members>
            <member id="1000020001"/>
            <member id="1000020002"/>
         </members>
      </activity>
   </activities>
</root>
```

the result will be:

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>Student: 1000020001</h3>
<b>Activity: </b>yoga beginners<br>
<b>Activity: </b>yoga intermediate<br>
<h3>Student: 1000020002</h3>
<b>Activity: </b>yoga intermediate<br>
</body>
</html>
```